# OpenLayers install npm install --save-dev parcel-bundler error

Tags: openlayers, installation

I am trying to setup OpenLayers on my computer.

I am following the directions here:
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html

But when I do:
npm install --save-dev parcel-bundler
I get error:

```
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
npm WARN ol@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN ol@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

How do I fix this?

I have tried searching for this on google and duckduckgo but to no avail.

I have found the first error described in more detail here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist/v/1.5.1

Don't get how to solve it though.

Comment: it's more likely parcel-bundler's issue.

Answer (score 2):

These are warnings, not errors. You can safely ignore them:

```
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
```

This tells you that if you are using browserslist v3 yourself, you could run into compatibility errors.

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
```

This can be safely ignored, as there is a fallback for fsevents on linux implemented.

```
npm WARN ol@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN ol@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

You can add content to the description field of your `package.json` file, but don't have to.